# Access CPanel Webmail using PHP

Tags: php, webmail

I have a domain and CPanel account with a host from which I can create email accounts.

I want to write a PHP script to connect to any of the created email accounts provided the username and password and view all the emails sent to this email inbox.

If this is possible I would like to have a guide in creating this kind of script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetching mail from a POP3 server using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165014/fetching-mail-from-a-pop3-server-using-php)

Comment: If the mailboxes support POP3 or IMAP, [this](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use POP3 or IMAP protocols that doesn't have anything to do with cPanel. Otherwise for cPanel account functions you would want to use their API at http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/AutomationIntegration/XmlApi#Account functions.

Comment: How can I connect to the email using the POP3 protocol using the PHP? I want to provide the username and password in a from (I can do it) ... Then I will send the username and password to a PHP page that will fetch the emails and display it in a table view

Comment: Check this out a little Google searching got me this cool class: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2-PHP-Access-to-e-mail-mailboxes-using-the-POP3-protocol.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Darren 100% there is no need to use Cpanel API to connect to the email,the email is still email and will work with conventional POP3 or IMAP protocols as mentioned above.