# Access to a POP server for cheking new emails and retrieving the subject and date using PHP

Tags: php, email, pop3

I'm implementing new ways to comunicate with my visitors, actually I use a sms gateway I programed a while ago, were my users send sms and then I proccess them using a php script.

Now I want to open a new way for comunication, email. So I want to develop a PHP script to access my google email account and check for new emails, retrieving the date and the subject.

So, firts to begin, I really like to hear your opinions of how to start and some best practices recommendations about this, and if is out there some libaries or already made scripts for doing this.

Thanks a lot, I am sorry about my English.

**PD: I DONT HAVE ACCESS TO php imap libary**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetching mail from a POP3 server using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165014/fetching-mail-from-a-pop3-server-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

As starters: http://docs.php.net/imap, http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_IMAP